# Why doesn't URL routing work in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, url-routing, cassini

Does anyone else have problems with running URL routing projects in Visual Studio?

The Visual Studio Web server doesn't seem to want to play nice with URL routing.  It doesn't invoke the engine at all in fact, which means you can't debug, and have to run the project out of IIS to get it work.

Is there a workaround for this?

**Edit:** By "URL routing" I mean the Microsoft framework in the "System.Web.Routing" namespace.

**Edit:** Using Web forms, not MVC.

Comment: What are you doing / using for "url routing"?

Comment: Clarified the question again.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's not configured correctly for the version of IIS that you are running locally.

[Here is a good resource](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/aspnet-routing-goodbye-url-rewriting/) for setting it up.   Can you post code?